# Installing couchbase client SDK for PHP on XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, xampp, couchbase

as I couldn't find any question regarding this subject and after getting in touch with Couchbase support I was finally able to setup couchbase PHP SDK on XAMPP on Windows (7 untimate in my case, but this should work on any version), so I went ahead and write this self-answered post so everyone with the same problem can fix this issue.

If you try to setup the couchbase PHP client SDK as explained on couchbase SDK page (http://www.couchbase.com/develop/php/current) it won't work as all they have at the time of this post are instructions for setting it up on linux and if you digg a little on the forums, you'll find the IIS explanation, it's not outlined how to make it work under XAMPP/apache.

If you uncompress the SDK files under the /php/ext folder and add the extension=php_couchbase.dll to the php.ini you will get an error when starting apache.

In order to make the couchbase PHP client SDK to work with XAMPP, you need to **move the libcouchbase.dll file to the /apache/bin/ folder**, move the the php_couchbase.dll file to the /php/ext/ folder and finally add the line

```
extension=php_couchbase.dll
```

to the /php/php.ini file (this is the default ini file).

BTW, as fas as I know, XAMPP deploys with the Thread Safe version of PHP, so you MUST download the library with the "TS" suffix (Windows PHP 5.3 TS, 32-bit or Windows PHP 5.4 TS, 32-bit, etc.) for your PHP version.

UPDATE:
As trondn mentions in a comment below: 
If you need to run php from command line (CLI), you need to copy libcouchbase.dll to c:\xampp\php. 
Alternatively you may copy libcouchbase.dll to the system directory to make it available for all binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post lack a an important detail I had in my post at http://trondn.blogspot.no/2013/04/couchbase-php-xampp-and-windows.html . You need to copy libcouchbase.dll to c:\xampp\php to be able to run php from the command line. Alternatively you may copy libcouchbase.dll to the system directory to make it available for all binaries.

Comment: isn't the C sdk couchbase a prerequisite in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/couchbase/1.1.5/ - download site for couchbase sdk PHP.

use php info to find info about your apache/php version (Compiler, Arhitecture, Thread safety) before download

libcouchbase.dll must be copied in the same directory with php.exe
php_couchbase.dll must be copied in the extension directory of php.

Comment: It didn't see it until I added the PHP folder to the paths Windows variable (Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Path) I had manually installed PHP so the path wasn't set.